# In ASP.NET Core, can you construct a class with sub-classes, that can then be injected into another project

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have to use a Rest service that has various resources with actions for those resources.

I would like to create a service that mimics that structure.

It would be something like `Service.Users.GetUserById("user1")` or `Service.Games.GetList()`

Each time I need to use the `Service`, I also need to pass in some parameters, for example:

```
var Service = new Service("apiKey")
```

and I would like the service to be available via ASP.NET Core dependency injection.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely you can. Infact, this is pretty common thing. You can create a class library where you will define your interface and implementation of your service. Interface is optional but it's highly recommended, as you are allowing the consumer of the library to follow SOLID pattern.
So, these are the steps:

Create a new class library project.
Then add your interface and implementation there as

```
public interface IService { }

internal class Service : IService { }
```

Then expose an extension method over `IServiceCollection`, which will allow you to inject your service in any DI container.

```
public static IServiceCollection AddMyService(this IServiceCollection serviceCollection)
{
    return serviceCollection.AddTransient<IService, Service>();
}
```

And that's it. Now to consume it in outside code, if that code is in the same solution, all you have to do is add a reference to your class library and then call that method in your startup class where you are registering your services.

```
serviceCollection.AddMyService();
```

And then you can inject IService in any DI constructor in your code and it will be automatically resolved. But if your consumer code is not in the same solution, then you will need to publish it as a nuget package either on private or public feed, and then you need to import that package where you want to use it. And just do the same as above in your startup code.

To pass the api key you can let it be passed from the configuration of your main project. You can achieve this by injecting the `IConfiguration` object into your `Service` constructor.

```
internal class Service : IService
{
    private readonly string _apiKey;
    public Service(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _apiKey = configuration.GetValue<string>("myApiKey");
    }
}
```

And just add a line in `appsettings.json` file, in your main api, your api key like

```
"myApiKey": "YOUR_SUPER_SECRET_API_KEY_HERE",
```